# uploadify and sql query

Tags: php, mysql, uploadify

i am using uploadify script to upload files as my school project.

```
//die($_SESSION['ID'].'.....'.$_SESSION['level']);

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $filename = substr(md5(time()), 0, 8)."-".$_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $filename;
    $time = time();
    $ID = $_SESSION['ID'];

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO files VALUES(NULL, '$ID', '$targetFile', '$time')");

    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
    echo "1";
}
```

On top $_SESSION['id'] is working, however when i entered inside $sql, it return as 0. Any idea why? i have rechecked everything.

Confused.

Thank you

Comment: It looks correct.  Store the query in a string and pipe it out before you send it to mysql_query. Then try running this directly against MySQL and verify it returns no errors.  If it successfully inserts directly, the problem is most likely the way you are connecting to MySql in PHP.

Comment: Also, echo SESSION['ID'] inside the  if (!empty($_FILES)) { //here } statement and lets see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems SESSION doesn't work well with uploadify, i solved it with scriptData uploadify.

Thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Must be the type of your mysql column.

Be sure your are using `varchar`/`text` because `'$ID'` is a `string` : if your type is `int` (or similar) then you WILL have `0` inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things wrong here. You should first be explicitly naming your fields in the $sql:

```
$sql = 'insert into tablename (fileid,filename,d_uploaded) values ('.$ID.', \''.$targetFile.'\', '.$time.');';
```

Most ID fields won't be VARCHAR they will be INT. All VARCHAR is a text field and all INT are numeric. You don't escape out your INT fields but you need to escape your VARCHAR.

Also don't insert NULL fields to get an auto increment field. By doing the SQL the way I have above you get the benefit of being able to only code the SQL fields you are inserting and the rest of the fields in the table will insert default values.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `INSERT INTO files SET field=value, field=value, ..` and remember to sanitize user input (like $_REQUEST) using `mysql_real_escape_string()` (and if you have magic quotes enabled to disable them if you decide to use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.